# ConvLSTM Error: expected lambda_7_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 66, 200, 3)

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

i made a ConvLSTM Layers but it doesnt work because of dimensions problem.

```
INPUT_SHAPE = (None, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS)
```

It's my inputs

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(24, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(36, (5, 5), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(48, (5, 5), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.summary()
```

It's the networks model.

```
history = model.fit_generator(batcher(data_dir, X_train, y_train, batch_size, True),
                    samples_per_epoch,
                    nb_epoch,
                    max_q_size=1,
                    validation_data=batcher(data_dir, X_valid, y_valid, batch_size, False),
                    nb_val_samples=len(X_valid),
                    callbacks=[checkpoint],
                    verbose=1)
```

And it's the fit generator.

but i got an error message.

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lambda_7_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (50, 66, 200, 3)

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lambda_7 (Lambda)            (None, None, 66, 200, 3)  0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_29 (ConvLSTM2D) (None, None, 66, 200, 24) 64896     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_27 (Batc (None, None, 66, 200, 24) 96        
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_30 (ConvLSTM2D) (None, None, 62, 196, 36) 216144    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_28 (Batc (None, None, 62, 196, 36) 144       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_31 (ConvLSTM2D) (None, None, 58, 192, 48) 403392    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_29 (Batc (None, None, 58, 192, 48) 192       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_32 (ConvLSTM2D) (None, None, 56, 190, 64) 258304    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_30 (Batc (None, None, 56, 190, 64) 256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_33 (ConvLSTM2D) (None, None, 54, 188, 64) 295168    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_31 (Batc (None, None, 54, 188, 64) 256       
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (TimeDist (None, None, 649728)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, None, 649728)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDist (None, None, 100)         64972900  
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_32 (Batc (None, None, 100)         400       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, None, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_8 (TimeDist (None, None, 50)          5050      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_33 (Batc (None, None, 50)          200       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)          (None, None, 50)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (TimeDist (None, None, 20)          1020      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_34 (Batc (None, None, 20)          80        
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_9 (Dropout)          (None, None, 20)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, None, 2)           42        
=================================================================
Total params: 66,218,540
Trainable params: 66,217,728
Non-trainable params: 812
```

Comment: What's the shape of your `x_train` and `y_train`? Also, it is generally not a good idea  to have more than one `None` in the layer output shapes.

Comment: @thushv89 sorry for the late answer. the results of print(X_train.shape) and print(y_traint.shape) are (10908,) and (10908,2). I did write batch size on Input but got a same error message

Comment: it's not the batch size you want to specify, it's the number of time steps (i.e. the second None). Also, your `X_train` has two features? But, why are you using a ConvLSTM? That is for 2D time series data (like videos)

Comment: @thushv89 X_train is a single image with 10908 samples. I tried to make prediction models (speed, steering angle). So it has 2 outputs. But for the speed predition i need rnn in order to know if the objects are closer or further. Cnn is not enough for it

Comment: So `X_train` is a single image with 10908 samples? Can you elaborate? What does "samples in an image" mean? Think it would be much better if you can give more details.

Comment: @thushv89 i recorded the pictures with a single camera on the demo car on the track frame by frame. Also i saved steering and speed values by each frames. The steering prediction works fine only with cnn cause it needed only picture data but for speed it must be known if the obstacles are closer or further to demo car in order to reduce/increase the speed

Comment: So, you have 10908 images and for each image you have a speed and a steering angle is it? If so what's the size of a single image?

Comment: @thushv89 the camera resolution is 1920 x 1280 but the Input size is 200 x66

Comment: @thushv89 and yes exactly. Actually 13636 images with validation

Comment: Okay now it makes more sense :) So I assume this is a single continuous stream of you driving/controlling the car through some path. What you can do is break down your single stream to smaller number of steps (e.g. 25/50/100 permitted by GPU memory) and use that as batches to train the ConvLSTM. Because there's no point in feeding 10908 as a single data-point spread across time. And LSTMs cannot remember that long anyway.

Comment: @thushv89 okay thank you i will try. But the problem was the input size not the steps. Do you mean the step size caused the problem?

Comment: @thushv89 and can you suggest how i can break down single stream? I have a betcher and batch size is 50

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know the problem but it's a bit difficult to articulate it. Let me give it a try with some diagrams

Comment: @thushv89 okay u need more infos to trying it?

Comment: No that's okay. All good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so there's a couple of things you have to understand.

### Defining the model.

So, your model should basically have an input of 5 dimensions. Those are,

- Batch dimension - (Automatically added by keras, so don't add that)
- Time dimension - Number of time steps in your series
- Image height
- Image width
- Image channels

And that's what the following model takes in. And if you look at model summary, there's only one None value (i.e. for batch dimension) in the output shape as it should be

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, ConvLSTM2D, BatchNormalization, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Dense, Flatten

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 66
IMAGE_WIDTH = 200
IMAGE_CHANNELS = 3
TIME_STEPS = 25
INPUT_SHAPE = (TIME_STEPS, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNELS)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/127.5-1.0, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(24, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(36, (5, 5), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(48, (5, 5), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20, activation='relu')))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
```

### Manipulating data

Your data is of following format at the beginning.

- Input - (10908, height, width, channels)
- Output - (10908, 2)

But the problem is you can't feed this as it is to the model as the model expects a 5 dimensional input. There are two options.

- **Option 1**: Make your input a (1, 10908, height, width, channels) by adding a new axis (i.e. `np.expand_dims`). But there's three problems with this.

  - Along with the model, a tensor of this large probably wouldn't fit in memory. Even if it does it'll take ages to train.
  - LSTMs cannot remember that long
  - Probably your model will heavily overfit as it only has a single data point
- **Option 2**: This is the **better** option. You break your data to chunks. So you break your 10908 to chunks of 25 (let's say). You can try other values like 50/100. I wouldn't recommend going beyond hundred as this is image data (due to memory / computational issues). But this will mean sacrificing few of your last images as you need the first axis (i.e. 10908) to be divisible by the number of timesteps you choose.

In other words, your model is no learning in chunks of 50 rather than trying to remember the full long stream, which usually generalizes better. And it makes sense too. It's not like you need to remember everything you did before to decide the steering angle and speed the last `n` frames would do.

**PS**: You can also be smart about this and help the model generalize even better. That is say, your batch size is 50 and TIME_STEPS is 25.

- You randomly sample a consecutive chunk (e.g. of 50*25)
- Reshape this to (50, 25, height, width, channels)
- Use that as the batch of data

This way, you have different chunks coming in different epochs which is better than doing the reshaping to the full set at ones, which will lead to seeing the same chunks in different epochs.

```
import numpy as np

x_train = x_train[:10900, :, :, :]
y_train = y_train[:10900, :]

x_train = x_train.reshape(-1,TIME_STEPS, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, TIME_STEPS, 2)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

### Fitting the model

Great with all that hard work done, you can now train your model.

`history = model.fit(x_train, y_train)`

I replaced your `fit_generator` with `fit` as I was feeling lazy and it still gets the point across.

Hope this helps.